# CAKeyframeAnimation not changing position as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, layer, cakeyframeanimation

I want to add an entrance animation to my UIView layer that left-shifts + fades-in with a slight bounce at the end. I assign a values array to `animation.values`, but when the animation runs, it seems to always skip the third value.

It appears as a left shift then right shift, instead of the desired left, right, left shift for the bounce effect.

Here is the code so far:

```
 CAKeyframeAnimation *leftShift = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
leftShift.duration = 0.5;
NSArray *viewPositionValues = @[
    @(myView.layer.position.x),
    @(myView.layer.position.x - 22),
    @(myView.layer.position.x - 18),
    @(myView.layer.position.x - 20)
];
leftShift.values = viewPositionValues;
leftShift.keyTimes = @[ @0, @.5, @.75, @1];
myView.center = CGPointMake(myView.layer.position.x - 20, myView.layer.position.y);

CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
opacityAnimation.fromValue = @0;
myView.layer.opacity = 1;
opacityAnimation.duration = 0.25;

CAAnimationGroup *entranceAnimation = [CAAnimationGroup new];
entranceAnimation.animations = @[ leftShift, opacityAnimation ];
entranceAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
entranceAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:completion];
[myView.layer addAnimation:entranceAnimation forKey:kSpeedMenuEntranceAnimationKey];
_speedMenuView.hidden = NO;
[CATransaction commit];
```

**Edit: Interestingly,  adding timing functions for each transition between timestamps specified in leftShift.keyTimes solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not given your animation group a duration. Therefore it has the default `0.25` second duration, and that is not long enough for the keyframe animation duration of `0.5` to play out in full.

So giving the animation group a sufficiently long duration will solve the problem of not seeing whole keyframe animation. On the other hand I would recommend that you go about this a completely different way and use UIKit dynamics or a springing animation to achieve the standard bounce effect, rather than trying to "build" a bounce from scratch, as it were.